# sendEmail after form submitted

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I've been trying to send an email after a autoform has been successfully submitted.  I've tried using the template.events  'submit' which didn't work and I've tried to use metermethod="sendEmail". Nothing I do seems to work. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Path: `form.html`

```
{{#autoForm collection="JobOffers" id="jobOfferForm" type="insert" meteormethod="sendEmail"}}
    <fieldset>
    {{> afQuickField name='firstName'}} 

    <button type="submit" data-meteor-method="sendEmail" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Path: `server/email.js`

```
sendEmail: function (from, subject, userId) {
    check([from, subject, userId], [String]);

    // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
    // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
    this.unblock();

    SSR.compileTemplate( 'htmlEmail', Assets.getText( 'html-email.html' ) );

    // to find the users info for the logged in users
    // var user = Meteor.user();
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: userId });
    var email = (user && user.emails[0].address);

    var emailData = {
      // name: (candidate && candidate.profile && candidate.profile.firstName),
      name: (user && user.profile && user.profile.firstName),

      // favoriteRestaurant: "Honker Burger",
      // bestFriend: "Skeeter Valentine"
    };

    Email.send({
      to: email,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      html: SSR.render( 'htmlEmail', emailData )
    });

    console.log('sendEmail sent');
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Path: `form.js`

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  jobOfferForm: hooksObject
});


var hooksObject = {
    after: {
        insert: function(error, result){
            Email.send({
                var otheruserId = FlowRouter.getParam('id');

                Meteor.call('sendEmail',
                'test@email.com',
                'Hello from Meteor!',
                otheruserId);       
            };          
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callbacks/hooks of autoform. If you want to send email after an insert following would be a solution:

```
var hooksObject ={
    after: {
        insert: function(error, result){
              //Send email here
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
var hooksObject = {
  after: {
    insert: function(error, result){
            var otheruserId = FlowRouter.getParam('id');

            Meteor.call('sendEmail',
            'test@email.com',
            'Hello from Meteor!',
            otheruserId);
    }
  }
};

AutoForm.addHooks('jobOfferForm', hooksObject);
```

Please refer to [autoform documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks) for more info.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your suggestion. Please excuse my lack of knowledge as I'm still learning meteor and programming. Hooks in general have me a little confused. I'm not sure where I'm suppose to put them. I've gone through the documentation however I'm not finding it to be much help. Would you mind taking a look at my update and letting me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not able to send yet. The build crashes on the line after after Email.Send

Comment: Do not you get any error message when build crashes?

Comment: if I remove email.send it builds fine however nothing happens when I submit the form

Comment: You have both Email.send and Meteor.call('sendEmail'...) together in your code. Fix it.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. It works! Can you update your update and remove the semicolon and a curly bracket so it works for others in the future. I tried to fix it for you but it wont let me. Thanks again!

Comment: I just did some testing. Is there a way to stop the email from sending if the form errors.

Comment: in insert callback you will have error object, so if error object exists do not send email. if(! error) Meteor.call('sendEmail'...)

Comment: Oh, that was easy. Thanks @Areca